# How to/should I list mentoring experience on my resume and LinkedIn?

Tags: software-industry, resume, work-experience, volunteering

I'm a young professional and have participated in mentoring programs offered by my university as an alumnus. Normally these programs involve mentoring students and helping them transition into university life or help them transition from university life into the professional world.

Should I list these programs on my resume and/or my LinkedIn profile, and if so, how should I list it?

On my resume, I was thinking I could make a new section for volunteer work and list them there or alternatively make a new "university connections" sub-section under the education section and list them there. For LinkedIn, I only really only have one option which is to put it under the volunteering section.

Comment: It goes in volunteering and you should add it :)

Comment: Mentoring is an important skill for the software industry (or any industry, really). Any proof you have done this before is invaluable.

Answer (score 5):

Then use the "volunteering heading".  Or you can add this as part of your overview in general terms and allow anyone interviewing you to explore this aspect of your experience in greater detail.

Or both - summarise in the main section and go into detail under "volunteering".

It's great that you do this by the way - transitioning to a working career is a wrench for many.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answer says you should list these under volunteering but you can also cut it as soon as you have other more important things to put on your resume and you want to make a 1/2 page mark.

I'm saying that because mentoring within your industry is somewhat expected and has benefits that will accrue to you naturally outside of what you should want to list on a resume. For example, you can ask the people you mentor to write a recommendation on your LinkedIn Profile. That does not take up space elsewhere and also looks a lot more organic.

In the long run, after the need to put this on your resume has gone, the fact that you have mentored these people will continue to help you professionally in lots of other ways.